# English expression for what Germans call 'Kompetenzgerangel'

Tags: expressions

In German *Kompetenzgerangel* means a situation between either persons or organisations (typically: government agencies, or departments in a company) where there is a lack of clarity about competencies of the individual parties, and parties try to grab competencies or responsibilities that others claim for themselves.

I tried to find an expression for that in English which has, like *Kompetenzgerangel*, an air of ironic criticism of the (childish, immature) behaviour of those involved.  However, dictionaries so far have not helped me. I found one suggestion: *bickering over competencies* but I do not know if I can trust the source.

Comment: 'Bickering over competencies' is perfectly grammatical but far from being a collocation. 'Bickering' strongly connotes (at least) childishness.

Comment: I have heard "interdepartmental rivalry" used to describe this, but it does not have the connotation of "ironic crticism of childish behaviour".

Comment: https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/pissing%20contest ?

Comment: Note that in English *competence* and *competency* tend to mean things like *capability* or *skill* rather than *responsibility* or *power* or *legal authority*, a common [confusion in Eurospeak](http://www.eca.europa.eu/Other%20publications/EN_TERMINOLOGY_PUBLICATION/EN_TERMINOLOGY_PUBLICATION.pdf)

Comment: What about "power struggle"? its more ambiguous, and very well could be a subtle thing that no one outside the company knows about.

Comment: What would be the advantage for the department, or bureaucratic office, to insist that their role carries greater responsibility thereby necessitating more work? In Italy the opposite is true, ever heard of the American expression ["The buck stops here"](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/the_buck_stops_here)? In Italy, where shifting blame is a national sport, the Italian public ask "What's does 'stop' mean?" So, I'm curious as to why  German officials would want to claim more power than they may actually possess. Is it a prestige thing, is it a fear of being one day made redundant?

Comment: @Mari-LouA, this seems to inadvertently refer to national stereotypes: Italy - whatever you can get away with; Germany - must follow the rules (so try to be the one that sets the rules.

Comment: @Chris H As an Italian speaker and inhabitant, who has banged her head against many a wall, I think I am allowed to generalise about Italian behaviour and habits :)

Comment: @Mari-LouA you are indeed. I've spent enough time in both countries to see where the stereotypes come from - and enough in Germany at least to see how limited they can be.

Comment: @Henry, while the linked paper does imply that *Power, Authority* are more common to express that sense, it primary concerns the uncountable property of the noun. However, There is no contradistinction between power and capability, skill, as the former implies the latter and ideally vice versa.

Comment: @Mari-LouA     You find both types of behaviour in the German civil service sector, "Das ist *meine* Aufgabe", and "Dafür bin ich nicht zuständig". It depends on circumstances. But they do not necessarily exclude each other: there are many cases where agencies both do not act on an issue, *and* actively prevent others from acting. Problably that's civil servants' heaven: being responsible for everything, but not doing anything.

Comment: @vectorious If you compare examples of [European Commission usage](http://ec.europa.eu/citizens-initiative/public/competences/faq) with [British Government usage](https://www.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/436073/cscf_fulla4potrait_2013-2017_v2d.pdf) there seems to me to be a fundamental distinction in intended meaning

Comment: Thanks @Henry for highlighting the competence / power confusion. I was wondering in what sense people "grab competencies".

Comment: @Henry, in either sense, *Kompetenzstreitigkeiten* is likewise meaningful, if those should be granted authority over a certain topic, if they are most capable. If only social competence is concerned, that is still a capability, even if social connections and soft skills are concerned. I believe in that sense *Power Play* is a generic term.

Comment: @vectorious You cannot grab social competence from somebody else. Even if you learn successful skills or behaviours from them, they still have the competence they already had, so *Streitigkeiten* does not apply in this case.  But you can take power or responsibility for decisions from them, and trying to do so can lead to *conflicts*.

Comment: @henry: Of course you can, you can keep beating a dead horse until the other side looses interest, for example.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

If I understand correctly, this is called a *turf battle* or *turf war*. [Oxford Dictionaries Online](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/turf_war) defines *turf war* (also *turf battle*) as:

> An acrimonious dispute between rival groups over territory or a particular sphere of influence.

I perceive a *turf battle* as less serious than a *turf war*. These terms are definitely used for disputes between government agencies and between divisions in a company.

If you want to make it sound immature or childish, you could use *turf squabble*, which isn't anywhere near as common as *turf battle* or *turf war*, but which I can find using Google search; everybody would understand what it means, and perceive it as less serious than a *turf battle* (which itself isn't always used for serious disputes).

Comment: Thanks. Perhaps to clarify: *Kompetenzgerangel* somehow implies not all too ferocious a competition. In *Kompetenzgerangel* the dispute would typically remain a little bit under the table cloth, not visible to everybody. - As you say "acrimoniuos dispute", this seems to be pointing towards a more ferocious battle, right?

Comment: That's the dictionary definition, and I think *acrimonious* for "turf battle" is a little strong. I've heard *turf battle* used for relatively trivial things (as well as for more bitter disputes); a *turf war* sounds more serious to me than a *turf battle*.

Comment: Mud-slinging is often involved, though. It goes with the territory. But patching up is fairly rare.

Comment: http://dict.leo.org/german-english/gerangel makes 'turf battle' seem very appropriate. 'turf battle' may be a little more general in explicit meaning than 'ein gerangel über Kompetenz' but it seems they should work in almost exactly the same situations.

Comment: See also **land grab**

Comment: See also **pissing contest**

Comment: Kompetenzgerangel is often more a war of attrition, tarpit strategies, sabotage by omission and countermanding than a fierce fight...

Comment: Turf battle and particularly turf battle bring to my (American) mind gang members killing each other more than white collar departments politicking.

Comment: @XiongChiamiov I agree. It is often used in Britain to describe battles between rival drug gangs over who has the "rights" to a particular set of streets, or entertainment venue. I could imagine it being used for a battle between two government departments, but with a strong sense of irony.

Comment: @Xiong Chiamiov: Look at [this headline](http://thehill.com/homenews/senate/335366-senators-locked-in-turf-battle-over-russia-probes) *"Senators locked in turf battle over Russia probes."* They're not going out on the streets and killing each other. (At least, I hope it's not going to come to that.)

Comment: For me (midwest US) the 'acrimonious dispute between parties within an organization' definition is primary for "turf war". I would understand the literal meaning as well, though.

Comment: *Turf **war*** is common in Britain too. *Turf **battle*** isn't but is obvious.

Answer (score 7):

Although a little uncouth:

> Pissing contest

[OED defines](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/pissing_contest) it as:

> vulgar slang
>   A contest or rivalry in which the main concern of the parties involved is the conspicuous demonstration of superiority.

It is usually used in the context of unimportant matters/competencies.

I have head it used in polite circles and in business situations, but always in the pejorative sense.

Comment: Interesting contribution, although a little bit off-center. In *Kompetenzgerangel* it is indeed the central point who gets the responsibility for a certain task; whereas, it seems, in your *pissing contest*, responsibility for a task is completely unimportant, it is more a form of general assertion of power and dominance, right?

Comment: @Christian yes. It's a childish "I'm better than you" contest measured by some skill that is irrelevant to the real issues at hand, and where someone being better at this skill carries no importance. In a literal sense it's a contest to determine who can piss the farthest, and similar in the figurative sense; a contest to determine who is the best at doing something that no one actually cares about.

Answer (score 3):

One option that is a little bit less casual sounding is **jurisdictional dispute**.

From **jurisdiction**:

> 3. The extent or range of judicial or administrative power; the territory over which such power extends.

- OED

This term usually refers to the realm of legal or executive power, but OED's definition 2 indicates that it can refer to a dispute over spheres of power more generally.

> 2. Power or authority in general; administration, rule, control.

Comment: 'Jurisdictional'  typo in first line... too small for edit.

Answer (score 1):

**Power Play**

> power play
>   1. Tactics exhibiting or intended to increase a person's power or influence.
>   ‘the sexual power play of their relationship’

*fight for power* is also translated as ger. *Machtkampf*.
However *power play* might also mean "2. Offensive tactics in a team sport", especially in American English. It appears that the childish connotation of play is reduced to actually fair games, whereas the term ***power struggle*** might embrace a serious undertone.

Answer (score 0):

**Play the angles** or **work the angles**

> 1. (idiomatic) To seek ways to advance one's self-interest, especially by making choices in a calculating or crafty manner; to scheme.
>
> 2012 June 21, "Editorial: Sanctions Against Iran," New York Times (retrieved 27 Feb 2014):
>   Iran, always playing the angles, is still trying to figure out how much economic pain it is willing to accept to maintain its nuclear ambitions and what, if anything, it is willing to give up.

Wiktionary "play the angles"